# Except a loop, how to calculate the BIC in R with the function 'BIC'

Tags: r

I have a sequence, for example: {A,B,A,B,A,A,A,A,B,A}, then we can get the frequency of this sequence for A and B.

```
A   7   \theta
B   3   1-\theta
```

According the definition of BIC: I should `-2*log(maximum likelihood of A and B)+K*log(Obs)` in this case, K=1 and Obs=10, maximum likelihood estimate for \theta is 7/10. I know how to do that with normal steps, but at this moment, I want to do that with the function in R, 'BIC' to get the result quickly, anyone could give me an explanation to do that?

Thanks

Comment: `BIC` can only calculate the BIC of a model. Apparently that's not what you want to do.

Comment: As Roland suggests see `?BIC` . What do you mean by fast? is `JacksBIC <- function(ML,K,Obs){-2*log(ML)+K*log(Obs)}` really to slow for you?